# How come I can pass functions to a lifted R.divide?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js, lifting

Given the following:

```
var average = R.lift(R.divide)(R.sum, R.length)
```

How come this works as a pointfree implementation of `average`? I don't understand why I can pass `R.sum` and `R.length` when they are functions and therefore, I cannot map the lifted `R.divide` over the functions `R.sum` and `R.length` unlike in the following example:

```
var sum3 = R.curry(function(a, b, c) {return a + b + c;});
R.lift(sum3)(xs)(ys)(zs)
```

In the above case the values in `xs`, `ys` and `zs` are summed in a non deterministic context, in which case the lifted function is applied to the values in the given computational context.

Expounding further, I understand that applying a lifted function is like using `R.ap` consecutively to each argument. Both lines evaluate to the same output:

```
R.ap(R.ap(R.ap([tern], [1, 2, 3]), [2, 4, 6]), [3, 6, 8])
R.lift(tern)([1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [3, 6, 8])
```

Checking the documentation it says:

> "lifts" a function of arity > 1 so that it may "map over" a list, Function or other object that satisfies the FantasyLand Apply spec.

And that doesn't seem like a very useful description at least for me. I'm trying to build an intuition regarding the usage of `lift`. I hope someone can provide that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first cool thing is that `a -> b` can support [`map`](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#map-method). Yes, *functions* are functors!

Let's consider the type of `map`:

```
map :: Functor f => (b -> c) -> f b -> f c
```

Let's replace `Functor f => f` with `Array` to give us a concrete type:

```
map :: (b -> c) -> Array b -> Array c
```

Let's replace `Functor f => f` with `Maybe` this time:

```
map :: (b -> c) -> Maybe b -> Maybe c
```

The correlation is clear. Let's replace `Functor f => f` with `Either a`, to test a binary type:

```
map :: (b -> c) -> Either a b -> Either a c
```

We often represent the type of a function from `a` to `b` as `a -> b`, but that's really just sugar for `Function a b`. Let's use the long form and replace `Either` in the signature above with `Function`:

```
map :: (b -> c) -> Function a b -> Function a c
```

So, mapping over a function gives us a function which will apply the `b -> c` function to the original function's return value. We could rewrite the signature using the `a -> b` sugar:

```
map :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
```

Notice anything? What is the type of [`compose`](https://sanctuary.js.org/#compose)?

```
compose :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

So `compose` is just `map` specialized to the Function type!

The second cool thing is that `a -> b` can support [`ap`](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#ap-method). Functions are also *applicative* functors! These are known as [Apply](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#apply)s in the Fantasy Land spec.

Let's consider the type of `ap`:

```
ap :: Apply f => f (b -> c) -> f b -> f c
```

Let's replace `Apply f => f` with `Array`:

```
ap :: Array (b -> c) -> Array b -> Array c
```

Now, with `Either a`:

```
ap :: Either a (b -> c) -> Either a b -> Either a c
```

Now, with `Function a`:

```
ap :: Function a (b -> c) -> Function a b -> Function a c
```

What is `Function a (b -> c)`? It's a bit confusing because we're mixing the two styles, but it's a function that takes a value of type `a` and returns a function from `b` to `c`. Let's rewrite using the `a -> b` style:

```
ap :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
```

Any type which supports `map` and `ap` can be "lifted". Let's take a look at [`lift2`](https://sanctuary.js.org/#lift2):

```
lift2 :: Apply f => (b -> c -> d) -> f b -> f c -> f d
```

Remember that `Function a` satisfies the requirements of Apply, so we can replace `Apply f => f` with `Function a`:

```
lift2 :: (b -> c -> d) -> Function a b -> Function a c -> Function a d
```

Which is more clearly written:

```
lift2 :: (b -> c -> d) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c) -> (a -> d)
```

Let's revisit your initial expression:

```
//    average :: Number -> Number
const average = lift2(divide, sum, length);
```

What does `average([6, 7, 8])` do? The `a` (`[6, 7, 8]`) is given to the `a -> b` function (`sum`), producing a `b` (`21`). The `a` is also given to the `a -> c` function (`length`), producing a `c` (`3`). Now that we have a `b` and a `c` we can feed them to the `b -> c -> d` function (`divide`) to produce a `d` (`7`), which is the final result.

So, because the Function type can support `map` and `ap`, we get `converge` at no cost (via [`lift`](https://sanctuary.js.org/#lift), [`lift2`](https://sanctuary.js.org/#lift2), and [`lift3`](https://sanctuary.js.org/#lift3)). I'd actually like to remove `converge` from Ramda as it isn't necessary.

---

Note that I intentionally avoided using [`R.lift`](http://ramdajs.com/0.22.1/docs/#lift) in this answer. It has a meaningless type signature and complex implementation due to the decision to support functions of any arity. Sanctuary's arity-specific lifting functions, on the other hand, have clear type signatures and trivial implementations.

Comment: Very nice!  I'd love to see this answer lifted into a blog post!

Comment: When `(b -> c -> d) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c) -> (a -> d)` is implemented as a combinator it looks like `bird = f => g => h => x => f(g(x)) (h(x))`. It looks similar to `psi = f => g => x => y => f(g(x)) (g(y))`. I wonder how the name of this bird is?

Comment: To answer my own question: It's the `starling'`, which is the composition of applicative's `ap` on functions `const ap = f => g => x => f(x) (g(x))` and composition `const comp = f => g => x => f(g(x))`: `const starling_ = comp(comp(ap)) (comp)`.

Answer (score 0):

As I have hard time understanding the same issue, I decided to take a peek from Ramda's source code. Will write a blogpost about this in the future. Meanwhile—I made a commented gist how Ramda's `lift` work step by step.

from: https://gist.github.com/philipyoungg/a0ab1efff1a9a4e486802a8fb0145d9e

```
// Let's make an example function that takes an object and return itself.
// 1. Ramda's lift level
lift(zipObj)(keys, values)({a: 1}) // returns {a: 1}

// this is how lift works in the background
module.exports = _curry2(function liftN(arity, fn) {
  var lifted = curryN(arity, fn);
  return curryN(arity, function() {
    return _reduce(ap, map(lifted, arguments[0]), Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)); // found it. let's convert no 1 to no 2
  });
});

// 2. Ramda's reduce level
reduce(ap, map(zipObj, keys))([values])
// first argument is the function, second argument is initial value, and the last one is lists of arguments. If you don't understand how reduce works, there's a plenty of resources on the internet

// 3. Ramda's ap level
ap(map(zipObj, keys), values)

// how ap works in the background
module.exports = _curry2(function ap(applicative, fn) {
  return (
    typeof applicative.ap === 'function' ?
      applicative.ap(fn) :
    typeof applicative === 'function' ? // 
      function(x) { return applicative(x)(fn(x)); } : // because the first argument is a function, ap return this.
    // else
      _reduce(function(acc, f) { return _concat(acc, map(f, fn)); }, [], applicative)
  );
});

// 4. Voilà. Here's the final result.
map(zipObj, keys)({a: 1})(values({a: 1}))

// Hope it helps you and everyone else!
```